# Subníveis {description} latex

Tags: latex

Trabalho no latex com a lista **{description}** porém seus subníveis são limitados. O máximo que conseguimos chegar é até sete níveis.

Após pesquisas na documentação do latex, encontramos o ambiente **{easylist}** porém o espaçamento e alinhamento precisa ser feito manualmente.

***Existe algum outro ambiente parecido com o {description} ou alguma maneira de aumentar o seu número de subníveis?***

Comment: Existe a comunidade apropriada na rede: https://tex.stackexchange.com/ , Sempre que preciso encontro a resposta nela.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! @Marconi

Comment: Por nada @Paulo, a comunidade é em inglês, mas fiz duas perguntas lá usando o tradutor do Google.